# Is there a way to loop through folder structure to find file name?

Tags: python, powershell

I want to be able to run a script that looks for a specific file name that contains text and a date that is 3 days later and returns a yes/no response based on the findings. I want to call a powershell script that would do this from a master python script. Basically I want the script to look in a subfolder called "PACP" and find a file with the name test_%date%_deliverable.mdb for example, and if say, its misspelled, to return a line noting the error. Are there any examples of scripts like this?

Comment: can you show an example of correct file name and a misspelled file name ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do this by hand with Python. You can use the [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module like this:

```py
import glob
date = "2021-01-01"
for f in glob.glob(f"PACP/**/test_{date}_deliverable.mdb"):
    # do something with the file matching the pattern
    print(f)
```

Depending what you want to do with the files you can also use the [pathlib module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob). The Path objects also support the same syntax with their glob() method.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
import os
from datetime import timedelta, date

# get the working directory 
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) 

# get current date
today = date.today()
formattedDate = today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

# search for file
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path + "/PACP"): 
    for file in files:  
        if file == "text_" + formattedDate + "_deliverable.mdb": 
            print("found file")
            quit()
    print("file not found")
    quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This for checking  misspelled file names in directory

```
from pathlib import Path
import re

for path in Path('PACP').rglob('*.mdb'):
    m = re.match(r"(test)_(\d{6})_(deliverable)", path.name)
    
   if m is None:
     print(path.name)
```

for example using a list of files from directory

```
files=[
'test_210127_deliverable.mdb',
'ttes_210127_derivrablle.mdb', #
'tset_2101327_deliveraxxle.mdb',# 
'test_210128_deliverable.mdb',
'test_210127_seliverable.mdb',#
'test_2101324_deliverable.mdb']#

for s in files:
    m = re.match(r"(test)_(\d{6})_(deliverable)",s)
    if m is None: print(s)
```

misspelled output:

```
ttes_210127_derivrablle.mdb
tset_2101327_deliveraxxle.mdb
test_210127_seliverable.mdb
test_2101324_deliverable.mdb
```

or a much more precise date matching `yyyy mm dd`  with a choice of 3 consistent separators: `_`,`-`,`.`

```
files=[
'test_2021-01-27_deliverable.mdb',
'test_2021.01.27_deliverable.mdb',
'test_2021_01_27_deliverable.mdb',
'test_2021-21-27_deliverable.mdb', 
'test_2021-01-72_deliverable.mdb', 
'tets_2021-01-27_deliverable.mdb',
'test_2021-01-27_delivvrable.mdb']

for s in files:
    m = re.match(r"(test)_(19|20)\d\d([-._])(0[1-9]|1[012])\3(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])_(deliverable)",s)
    if m is None: print(s)
```

misspelled output (more precise in date matching)

```
test_2021-21-27_deliverable.mdb
test_2021-01-72_deliverable.mdb
tets_2021-01-27_deliverable.mdb
test_2021-01-27_delivvrable.mdb
```